# sorting a OrderedDict dictionary with duplicated float values

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary named `dict` that stores names and float averages, and I want to store the sorted averages with names in a file, but when I use a loop to find the key (students' names) it prints duplicated name.

```
print(dict)
sorted_list = sorted(dict.values() , key = float)

sorted_dict = list()
for i in sorted_list:
    for j in dict:
        if dict[j] == i:
            sorted_dict.append([j,dict[j]])
            break
print(sorted_dict)
```

Take a look at the output:

```
OrderedDict([('mandana', '5'), ('hamid', '6.066666666666666'), ('sina', '11.285714285714286'), ('sara', '9.75'), ('soheila', '7.833333333333333'), ('ali', '5'), ('sarvin', '11.375')])

[['mandana', '5'], ['mandana', '5'], ['hamid', '6.066666666666666'], ['soheila', '7.833333333333333'], ['sara', '9.75'], ['sina', '11.285714285714286'], ['sarvin', '11.375']]
```

Comment: By the way, usually it's considered bad practice to name variables the same as built-in types or functions. So in this case many would tell you that you should not name a dictionary `dict`.

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm looks up the name corresponding to a given number. This leads to wrong results if the same number occurs for more than one name. Here, for `5`, which actually belongs to `'ali'`, it finds `'mandana'` first and includes it instead.

You can directly sort the name, value pairs by passing `dict.items` instead of `dict.values` to `sorted`. The `key` function would then have to take the second item of each pair and convert it to a float.

```
sorted_dict = sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda pair: float(pair[1]))
```